# How to reduce Vuetify Grid column width for bigger screen sizes

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, css-grid

I am using `vuetify` grid system to build a reply component. With column ratio of 1:11 for icon and reply column respectively. Below is the code for it

```
<v-row justify="center" class="ma-0 pa-0">
    <v-col
      id="vote-col"
      cols="1"
      class="pa-0 d-flex flex-column align-center"
    >
      <v-icon size="24">mdi-thumb-up</v-icon>
      <span>{{ likes }}</span>
    </v-col>
    <v-col id="question-col" cols="10" class="pa-0">
      <v-row class="ma-0 replyFont">
        {{ reply }}
      </v-row>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
```

This looks fine on smaller screens. But as we go on the screen sizes above 1100px, even `cols="1"` becomes too wide and creates a lot of space between the icon column and the reply column as seen in the pictures below

[image]
[image]

How to fix `v-col` having more width than required? I know I can't go less than `1` for `cols` property. How you guys been handling this?

Comment: Did you tried to apply `max-width` style on the 1st `v-col`?

Comment: @MichalLevý as a CSS workaround it does help but do we have anything from the vuetify grid sytstem?

Comment: I don't think so. Setting `cols="1"` will use CSS class with `max-width: XX%` where XX is computed as `100/12 * number of columns` (you can check that yourself in Devtools) so your only option is to override it by your own style...

Answer (score 10):

You could use `cols="auto"` to make the column the width of its content, and then no cols attribute on the other column to allow it to grow the remaining width.

```
    <v-row justify="center" class="ma-0 pa-0">
            <v-col id="vote-col" cols="auto" class="blue py-0 d-flex flex-column align-center">
                <v-icon size="24">mdi-thumb-up</v-icon>
                <span>0</span>
            </v-col>
            <v-col id="question-col" class="pa-0">
                <v-row class="ma-0 replyFont">
                    ...
                </v-row>
            </v-col>
    </v-row>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/pX7pin7b4L

Answer (score 3):

Setting `cols="X"` will use Vuetify CSS class `col-X` which is defined like

```css
.col-X {
    flex: 0 0 YY%;
    max-width: YY%;
}
```

where YY is computed as `100/12 * X` where X is value pased to `cols`. `X` can be only whole number and minimum is 1.

That means minimum width of the column is 8.33333... percent

If you want something smaller (or fixed), you must apply your own style with `max-width` CSS attribute...